# Unexpected exception thrown by Convert.ToDecimal

Tags: c#, .net, types, scientific-notation

This is probably an old one but I can't find anything on it.  Does anyone have any idea why this:

```
Convert.ToDecimal("3.14521963414679E-08")
```

throws

> FormatException ("Input string was not in a correct format.")

However this works as expected?

```
Convert.ToDouble("3.14521963414679E-08")
```

I thought Convert.ToDecimal could handle exponentials - maybe I got that wrong.

Comment: Which kind of exception?

Comment: Possibly because of the `E-` part?

Comment: A FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."  I thought Convert.ToDecimal could handle exponentials?

Comment: Don't put additional info in comments, edit the question.

Comment: [`double.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) can, but [`decimal.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx) can't. Those are the methods called, when doing `Convert.To...`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Convert.ToDecimal` doesn't support the scientific notation.

It is documented that `Convert.ToDecimal` internally uses `Decimal.Parse` and the [documentation for `Decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx) states that this uses `NumberStyles.Number` and thus only the following is a valid input:

```
[ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws]
```

To support scientific notation you will have to use another overload of `Decimal.Parse` that allows you to specify the `NumberStyles` to be used:

```
var result = decimal.Parse("3.14521963414679E-08",
                           NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
```

Comment: Erh..I don't understand why this answer wasn't selected.

Comment: This actually answered the question even more usefully so I've switched this to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToDecimal()` method uses `Decimal.Parse()` explicitly.

From *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)*;

> Indicates that the numeric string can be in exponential notation. The
>   AllowExponent flag allows the parsed string to contain an exponent
>   that begins with the "E" or "e" character and that is followed by an
>   optional positive or negative sign and an integer. In other words, it
>   successfully parses strings in the form nnnExx, nnnE+xx, and nnnE-xx.
>   **It does not allow a decimal separator or sign in the significand or
>   mantissa; to allow these elements in the string to be parsed, use the
>   AllowDecimalPoint and AllowLeadingSign flags**, or use a composite style
>   that includes these individual flags.

You can use [`Decimal.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx) overload of this method which allows you to use [`NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) enumration like;

```
Decimal.Parse("3.14521963414679E-08",
              NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/l82pJ4).

Comment: Thanks - that's a really useful addition Soner

Answer (score 0):

Because of this->

ToDecimal(String)--Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent ***decimal number.***.

ToDouble(String)--Converts the specified string representation of a number to an ***equivalent double-precision floating-point number.***

for further clarification visit-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert_methods.aspx

Hope it helps..:)